# spring <util:properties /> with wildcards

Tags: spring, properties

I'd like to load key-value pairs from multiple locations. My first guess was:

```
<util:properties id="requestProcessorRepository"
  location="classpath*:*requestProcessors.properties"/>
```

but it is not valid

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath*:*requestProcessors.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:546)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 24 more
```

Without wildcards, it starst to work.

So any other possibilities to create a properties object / map from wildcarded files?

Comment: Ok, to make it clearer, I'd like to load all files matching a pattern, and in a specific directory loaded. Say `META-INF/*RequestProcessor.properties`. So I put such resources under `src/main/resources/META-INF/` directory (maven structure).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, your resource path `classpath*:*requestProcessors.properties` is not reliable (from [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-wildcards-in-path-other-stuff)):

> Please note that "classpath*:" when
>   combined with Ant-style patterns will
>   only work reliably with at least one
>   root directory before the pattern
>   starts, unless the actual target files
>   reside in the file system. This means
>   that a pattern like "classpath*:*.xml"
>   will not retrieve files from the root
>   of jar files but rather only from the
>   root of expanded directories.

If you solve this problem, you can load properties as follows:

```
<bean id = "requestProcessorRepository" 
    class = "org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name = "locations" 
        value = "classpath*:somefolder/*requestProcessors.properties" />
</bean>
```

(Original version of the code was more complex, but there is no need in it, since Spring converts path with wildcards to `Resource[]` automatically).

Comment: So should your solution load all files ending with `requestProcessors.properties` inside somefolder in the classpath root?

Comment: @pihentagy: Yes. I guess you can use your original path too if your classpath consists of expanded directories.

Comment: Argh, I tried with `name="location"`, which should be `name="locations"`. Thanks for the answer