# How to use property file in util:properties?

Tags: java, spring, properties

I must use spring `util:properties`, however, I need something like this:

```
if propertyFile x exists, use x, otherwise, use y.
```

Can you please advise how I can obtain this?

Answer (score 0):

May be this is half solution! Spring can load the wildcard resources. Please see [spring <util:properties /> with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016103/spring-utilproperties-with-wildcards)

In this way you can name your files like: **x-config.properties** and **y-config.properties**:

```
<bean id = "config" 
    class = "org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name = "locations" 
        value = "classpath*:somefolder/*-config.properties" />
</bean>
```

If both x and y exist both of them are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is an option `ignoreResourceNotFound`, but it isn't available for namespace component. You have to use `PropertiesFactoryBean` directly:

```
<bean id="props" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations" value="y.properties, x.properties"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

If your `x.properties` doesn't exist, it will be ignored and the properties from `y.properties` will remain.

If `x.properties` exists and it contains the same `keys` as `y.properties`, they override those from `y.properties`, because all `locations` are loaded one by one respectively.